# (re-)importing a maven project into intellij turns off aspectj post compile mode

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, aspectj

I have a Maven project with AspectJ and Lombok.

After many hour of struggling to make it build correctly both on Eclipse and IntelliJ, I found that in IntelliJ it should have the "post compile weave mode" checkbox enabled under relevant module 's AspectJ facet.

However, no matter what I tried, this checkbox always get unchecked when reimporting the Maven project. When checking it and warning appears saying that this facet is imported from Maven and any changes might be lost after reimporting.

Any suggestion about what to change in my `pom.xml` in order to have this checkbox enabled after reimporting?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible. Please vote for the related request and follow it for updates:https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-193838/Enable-post-compile-weave-mode-for-all-projects-in-one-place

Comment: That issue is about setting post-compile mode for multiple modules at once. Nowhere does it relate to the problem of Maven re-import overwriting the setting, once the user has activated it for all relevant modules. That problem would require to either create a separate issue or to find an existing one.